# cannot create android project in a xamarin forms portable solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I just installed **vs 2015 update 2**, installing as componenent both **xamarin** and **android sdk**, setup level **19,21,23**.
I have **android studio** installed and working in the same computer.
If I try to create a new solution using a *xamarin.forms portable template* I have this error while creating the android setup:

```
A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'Hello.Droid'. Value cannot be null.   
Parameter name: path1.
```

looking in the output window I see

```
[I:unknown]  Did not find Android Sdk  
[I:unknown]  Found Xamarin Sdk 6.0.3
```

Even unnecessary, I tried to add the ANDROID_HOME and relative paths in the environment variables and restarted vs, but without success.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Check Xamarin knows the correct Android SDK path. Navigate in Visual Studio to *Tools* > *Options* > *Xamarin* > *Android Settings*.